# unable to run command on rumtime from java

Tags: java, runtime

I'm trying to start docker from my java application, this is the code:

```
Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("docker --help");
int x1 = p1.waitFor();
System.out.println((new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p1.getInputStream()))).readLine());
System.out.println(path);
```

But I have this error:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "docker": error=2, No such file or directory
```

What is  the problem? Docker is installed on my Mac!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*No such file or directory* means, 'Runtime' couldn't find the docker binary. You should run the command with the full path.

Additionally you should work with the *ProcessBuilder*, it's easier to use.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("[PATH]/docker.exe", "-help");
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process process = pb.start();
try (var infoStream = process.getInputStream()) {
  infoStream.transferTo(System.out);
}
status = process.waitFor();
```

Keep in mind, depending on what you want to do, it could be necessary to set the working directory, with:

```
pb.derectory([PATH]);
```

For further information have a look on my blog article: https://thilosdevblog.wordpress.com/2022/09/18/how-to-properly-handle-the-output-of-the-processbuilder/